# Passing props to the handler of React router in the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, reactjs, react-router

I'm following the example reported in the react-router guide

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <div>Hi</div>;
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Route handler={App} path="/" />
);

// if using express it might look like this
app.use(function (req, res) {
  // pass in `req.url` and the router will immediately match
  Router.run(routes, req.url, function (Handler) {
    var content = React.renderToString(<Handler/>);
    res.render('main', {content: content});
  });
});
```

Quite simple, isn't it? Instead this is my code:

```
export function index(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function) {
    Router.run(routes, req.url, (Handler, state) => {
        fs.readFileAsync(
            path.join(__dirname, '..', 'mockData/airport-codes.csv'),
            'utf-8'
        ).then((content) => {
            return csv.parseAsync(content);
        }).then((parsedContent: Array<string[]>[]) => {
            ResponseHelper.renderTemplate('index', res, {
                output: React.renderToString(React.createElement(Handler, {
                    header: [
                        "ID", "Type", "Name", "Latitude (deg)", "Longitude (deg)", "Elevation", "Continent", "Country ISO", "Region ISO", "Municipality", "GPS Code", "IATA Code", "Local Code"
                    ],
                    initialData: parsedContent
                }))
            });
        }).catch(next);
    });
}
```

Basically what I do is get data and pass to the Handler to initialise the component.  This is the file route in react:

```
import { Route } from "react-router";
import * as React from "react";

import Excel from "../components/Excel";

export default (
  <Route handler={Excel} path="/" name="excel" />
);
```

and this is the entrypoint in the frontend

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as Router from "react-router";

import routes from "./shared/routes";

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, (Root, state) => {
  React.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

My problem is that when I start the application I get this warning:

```
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `header` was not specified in `Excel`. Check the render method of `Router`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `initialData` was not specified in `Excel`. Check the render method of `Router`.
```

and consequently an error. Do you know which is the right way to pass props in this case?

EDIT

error message

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
1../components/Excel @ bundle.js:4s @ bundle.js:1e @ bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:1
```

Comment: I fixed the error in the server and now it is render correctly from the server but not in the client. It seems that the rendering in the server works correctly but not that in the client

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle of the isomorphic app like yours is that first, the server runs the JS code and return an HTML string expression of the rendered result. It mounts that to the DOM and then loads your frontend app on top of that. Of course the DOM should be identical so it doesn't need to really rerender anything, but it does mount all of the JS event handlers, React code, etc to the window.

It will still process the `Router.run` method and match the routes, but it will be the same page that was loaded from the server. However, after that point, the front-end has to replicate the server side functionality (ie fetching the data, passing to the routed component).

So, in your frontend code you need to fetch the required data that you would normally do on the server, and pass it down to the `<Root />` component as props.

Check out this demo, specifically the `app/server.js` (server side render) and `app/client.js` (client side render). Hope this helps!

[React Router Mega Demo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-mega-demo)

Comment: I have made some changes to the my code and now that warning and errors don't appear anymore but now I get the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & the server is rendered correctly

Comment: You can check the complete code here https://github.com/mazzy89/expressjs-typescript

Comment: I'm getting a "Can't find module '../server' error.. am I missing something? Or can you just paste the full error message you received?

Comment: Did you use a transpiler typescript?js files aren't included

Comment: Oh no, sorry. I don't have the bandwidth to set that up right now, could you post the error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87920/discussion-between-brad-bumbalough-and-mazzy).